# if statement in HANA information models

Tags: hana

I have created three new calculated columns based on existing flag fields A,B, C.

and logic is

**1)** if flag fields (A or B or C) equals to 'X'
Field 1 will be 'X'.

**2)** if flag fields (A and B) or (B and C) or (A and C) equals to 'X'
field 2

**3)** if flag fields (A and B and C) = 'X'
Field 3.

Could you please suggest the code for **HANA**.

Comment: This works,                                                                                                1) if("A" = 'X' or "B"  = 'X' or "C"= 'X' , 'X', 'No Value' )                                                                                                         2) Still waiting for Answers.                                                                                                      3)  if( "A" = 'X' and "B"  = 'X' and "C" ='X','X', 'No Value')

Answer (score 1):

Please check following CASE statements

```
select
*,
case when A = 'X' or B = 'X' or C = 'X' then 'X' else NULL end as Field1,
case when (A = 'X' and B = 'X') or (A = 'X' and C = 'X') or (B = 'X' or C = 'X') then 'X' else NULL end as Field2,
case when A = 'X' and B = 'X' and C = 'X' then 'X' else NULL end as Field3
from Flags;
```

Comment: Hi Eralper,                                                                                        Thanks for your reply, but am looking for SQL statement in HANA Studio; Where only possible syntax is...                                                   If (Condition , do true, do false).                              else is not allowed. But yes another If statement is possible.

Comment: So this is what my guess is...                                                                      IF ("A" and "B" = 'X', 'X', If ("B" and "C" , 'X', If ( "A" and "C" , 'X' ,  'No Value')))                                                                                                  but this giving me and error too.

Comment: I actually use the code on HANA Studio. Where do you use this in a CDS view, HDB procedure, calculated view, etc or in which perspective do you use?

Comment: HANA Studio  > Calculated View > Calculated Column

Comment: Voila ... issue resolved.                                                                               Here is the solution :                                                                                   if("A" = 'X' and  "B" = 'X' , 'X', if ("B" = 'X' and "C" = 'X', 'X', if ("A" = 'X' and "C" = 'X' ,'X', 'No value')))

Comment: Good news. And for Field3, you have probably following IF clause: if("A" = 'X' and "B" = 'X' and and "C" = 'X', 'X', 'No value')

Comment: @Erapler : Your help is appreciated . Thank you very much.